# SwiftUI force-unwrap

Tags: swiftui

```
init() {
    let locations = ChurchLocationsDataService.locations
    self.locations = locations
    self.mapLocation = locations.first!
    self.updateMapRegion(location: locations.first!)
}
```

Guys, tell me how I can safety unwrap this?

I'm trying to do this, but I get an error

```
init() {
    let locations = ChurchLocationsDataService.locations
    self.locations = locations
    guard self.mapLocation = locations.first else { return }
    guard self.updateMapRegion(location: locations.first) else { return }
}
```

Comment: Put the `guard` on `locations.first`

Comment: `Closure expression is unused`

Comment: another option would be to make self.mapLocation optional. You can more safely use a guard to unwrap it after the initialiser

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simply provide a default if `locations.first!` fails:

```
init() {
    self.locations = ChurchLocationsDataService.locations
    // If locations.first fails, you can simply use some default
    let firstLocation = ChurchLocationsDataService.locations.first ?? CLLocation(latitude: 0, longitude: 0)
    self.mapLocation = firstLocation
    self.updateMapRegion(location: firstLocation)
}
```

You can't use the `guard` statements and return because the `init()` requires that everything be initialized. Failing in a `guard` means that isn't the case.